# Access token being set to none while creating databricks linked service in Azure Data Factory (ADF) using python

Tags: python, azure, access-token, databricks, azure-data-factory

I am creating a databricks activity in Azure Data Factory V2 using python.

```
ls_databricks_name = 'databricks_linkedservice'                       
acc_token = SecureString('d***')                            
ls_azure_databricks = AzureDatabricksLinkedService(connect_via=IntegrationRuntimeReference('integrationRuntimedev'), 
                                                   access_token=acc_token, 
                                                   domain='https://eastus.azuredatabricks.net',  
                                                   existing_cluster_id='***')
```

When I run this code, the linked service reference is created successfully with access_token having the value provided and type as SecureString.
[value of ls_azure_databricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIWbf.png)

```
ls_db = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_databricks_name, ls_azure_databricks)
```

But when I run the above line, linked service is created with all fields populated correctly except access_token which is 'None'.
[value of ls_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b2Ai.png)